# Java type parameterized Class argument

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

JPA has a method of the following signature:

```
<T> CriteriaQuery<T> createQuery(Class<T> resultClass);
```

How do I invoke this method when my `resultClass` type is, itself, type parameterized?

For example:

```
public class ResultDto<T> {
...
}
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
createQuery(ResultDto<String>.class);
```

Comment: Can't type this into an IDE right now, but have you tried `<ResultDO<String>> createQuery(ResultDo.class)` ?

Comment: My IDE says "incompatible types".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Class` instance for any specific instantiation of a generic type (e.g. `ResultDto<String>`, `ResultDto<Integer>`, `ResultDto<MyObject>`, ...).

No matter whether the class is generic or not there is always only one `Class` instance which represents raw version of the class. In your case, it is `ResultDto.class`.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying - you are talking about the effect of Type Erasure, where type constraints are applied only at compile time and generic type information is removed at runtime, so only one instance can represent the raw version of the class. But I don't see how that prevents me from differentiating ResultDto<String> and ResultDto<Integer>, they are different types according to the Java compiler. I'd have to do an unchecked cast in order to get one from the other and make the compiler happy.

Comment: IMO, ultimately we can blame the type-erasure. But immediate reason here is because there is only `ResultDto.class`. If you let the compiler infer the return type by passing `ResultDto.class`, the inference system infers the return type to be `CriteriaQuery<ResultDto>`. Which of course isn't what you want. On the other hand, if you want to avoid type inference by doing something like `obj.<ResultDto<String>>createQuery(...)`, then you don't have the argument because there is no `ResultDto<String>.class`. AFAIK, you have two choices, either make the class not generic, or suppress the warnings.

Comment: Actually, given that query results are returned in a List, I can't even cast it from List<ResultDto> to List<ResultDto<String>>. So my only choice seems to be not to use generics...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createQuery(ResultDto.class)`

The reason is when you are going to create a object of ResultDto , you will always create it using a type parameter 
for eg
 `ResultDTo<String> rs = new ResultDTo<String>()`
So this type parameter will be considered in the `<T> CriteriaQuery<T> createQuery(Class<T> resultClass);`

Comment: I know that I can use createQuery(ResultDto.class) provided that I create the dto object as new ResultDto<String>(). It's just that (1) I would prefer to rely on the JDK compile time check, if possible (isn't that the whole point of type parameterization?), and (2) I'd like to avoid having to do an unchecked cast - without it I won't be able to compile. Somewhere along the way the value has to be cast to the expected/correct type.

Comment: You can safely rely on the JDK compile time check. eg `public static <T> void test(T[] arr){
  for(T t : arr){
   System.out.println(t);
  }
 }`  you can safely call the method using Integer[] or String[] , now if you call using int[] , it will fail at compile time itself.